# How do SMTP and POP-Server hand over emails?

Tags: python, email, smtp, pop3

For studying purposes I am playing with relaying emails via SMTP (in Python).
Now, assuming that I have reached the destination SMTP server, how is the handover to the local POP server realized?

I know that the POP server basically just reads a text file with all the messages in it, so does the SMTP-Server simply dump the received message into the required format?

I had a hard time trying to find anything more specific than just "the SMTP server then hands over the email to the POP server."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: Veto: I am asking this in order to know what ways there are to IMPLEMENT this.

Comment: Then show us some code where you need that and be more specific on what information you need exactly. We do neither deliver documentation from other source nor explain a whole protocol (or a whole set of protocols in this case) on SO.